# Unable to list all pdf files on device on android 10 and above

Tags: android, mediastore, storage-access-framework, file-storage, scoped-storage

Due to changes in storage framework, I am unable to list all the pdf files on the device.
This is my code :

```
String pdf = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
Uri table = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
String[] column = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};
String where = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
String[] args = {pdf};
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(table, column, where, args, null);
```

Is there any other way to get all the pdf files on the device?
There must be some workaround for this (apart from requestLegacyExternalStorage) as many apps depend on working with files(images, audio) that lie outside their scoped storage.

Comment: Use column .RELATIVE_PATH instead of .DATA.

Comment: Already tried RELATIVE_PATH, didn't work.

Comment: Then you should better explain what does not work and or post more code to illustrate. Telling it does not work is not very informative.

Comment: Whether I use DATA or RELATIVE_PATH, cursor.getCount is 0. If I use requestLegacyStorage flag, then it works fine and cursor points to pdf files present in the device and cursor.getCount() returns the number of pdf files on external storage. But this is a temporary solution and this flag won't be supported in android 11. I'm looking for the right way to get and display all pdf files present in the device.

Comment: Where and how did you/did your app store those pdf files? The media store will not tell you about all files on your device anymore.

Comment: My app did not store pdf files. It just displayed all the pdf on the device in a list. If the MediaStore won't tell about all files, then is there any other way? I just need a list of all pdf file names stored on the device. Is it even possible now?

Comment: If your app did not store them then who did? I asked that before. And where?

Comment: Do not select on mimetype. Just do without. Then see if .DISPLAY_NAME ends on .pdf.